# Don't restart Xcode tests on crash

Tags: xcode, xctest

Some code is producing corrupt memory and unit tests crash fairly randomly. Now I want to bisect the repo to find the buggy commit. Unfortunately Xcode automatically resumes on test case crashes (just restarts it).

How can I prevent Xcode to restart the unit tests after a crash?